# OSM converter cannot convert after renaming PBF to OSM?

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, osmosis

I downloaded a .pbf file from [this link](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany/baden-wuerttemberg/tuebingen-regbez.html) and then I renamed it to `tu.osm` because it is an .osm file.

Then I used osmconverter to convert it to .pbf using:

```
c:\osm>osmconvert tu.osm --out-pbf >tu.pbf
```

but I receive an error:

```
Error: could not open input file
```

despite the file is 64032 kb

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 3):

You can't just rename a *.osm.pbf file to *.osm because PBF is a binary file type and OSM a XML file type. This will make your OSM file invalid and it's no longer readable.
Instead, download *.osm.bz2 and unzip the file so it will be a valid *.osm file. However, osmconvert is also [capable to read *.osm.bz2](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert#Converting_Files) files.